# Adding a proper circle around HTML hex code of "tick" icon

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a css code [here as plunktr](https://plnkr.co/edit/PtpOkKKwmvr2DRX1?open=lib%2Fscript.js). I am able to draw icons using HEX code, but I am not able to make perfect circle using css for the tick icon.

Here is what I have used:

```css
.tick-icon::after {
  content: '\2713';
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

What I see is more like an oval shape. How to make it a perfect circle ?

Comment: Try adding padding relative to the font-size. So you can add `padding: 1rem`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a circle the pseudo element has to have height and width set to the same dimension. If this isn't done specifically then the system just bases the size on the dimensions of the character, which are not square.

This snippet uses a CSS variable to set the font size (as you have in your code) and then does a calculation to set the dimension of the surrounding pseudo element - obviously change the multiplier to what you want.

```css
.tick-icon {
  position: relative;
}
.tick-icon::after {
  --size: 10rem;
  content: '\2713';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: var(--size);
  --dimension: calc(1.5 * var(--size));
  width: var(--dimension);
  height: var(--dimension);
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="tick-icon"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Set width/height:

```css
.tick-icon::after {
  content: '\2713';
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 2rem;
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```